# Strict Form for Maclaurin Series

Tags: power-series

I have arrived at a expression $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1)(x^n +x^{n-1})$ in a Maclaurin series question.

Is this a suitable form? If not, how do I adjust what I already have?

Comment: No. You need to combine the $x^n$ and $x^{n-1}$.

Comment: May I ask how? Apologies if this is an absent minded question...

Comment: It is not clear from your expression what's the coefficient of, say, $x^7$, so it is not a suitable form.

Comment: But similarly, isn't it also unclear to read off the coefficient of $x^7$ from the expression given as an answer? You still need to inspect when $n=7,8$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1)(x^n +x^{n-1})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1)(x^n+\frac{x^n}{x})=(1+\frac{1}{x})\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1)x^n$$